# animate images using my toggle function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation

I have made my `Toggle()` function that alternates an image (changes the images to different colors when pressed).

I now want to *animate* the images, so basically call my `Toggle()` function, but leave a time delay between calls to make it look like a transition/animation.

What would be the best way to do this?

Note: I already have the function code, I just need a way to call the function with a time delay etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to implement a time delay in Javascript is with set timeout:

```
setTimeout(function(){alert("hi")}, 3000);
```

The first argument is a function that will be executed after the delay (you can either pass an anonymous function as shown here or a named one on some object like: "MyThing.doSomething"). The second argument is the desired delay in milliseconds.

For a detailed analysis of timers in Javascript, see [John Resig's How Javascript Timers Work](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/).